# How do I read and print variables from a file in Fortran?

Tags: windows, fortran, command

I have a problem with a fortran code. The problem is that I have a file with 14 columns and 644 lines. I use these commands but my .exe file does not showing what I would like and finally crashed.

Could you please tell me which command should I use in order to make it?

I have to mention that every time I would not have the same dimension (number of lines and rows) files.

What I have tried:

I thing I should try parameter or dimension command
but I am not sure how to syntax it.

```
parameter (len=644) ! lines
dimension A(len,14) !rows
C real IMM, lat, lon
character header*110,Var1(len)*4,Var2(len)*8,Var3(len)*8
+ ,Var4(len)*8,Var5(len)*8,Var6(len)*8,Var7(len)*8,Var8(len)*8,Var9(len)*8,
+ ,Var10(len)*8, Var11(len)*8,Var12(len)*8,Var13(len)*8,Var14(len)*8,header_append*97
open(7,file='testdata.txt',status='old')
open(8,file='EX-1.out',status='unknown')

do i=1,len
write(*,5) A(i,1)
end do


5 format(2x,f3.1)

do i=1,ip
write(*,5) A(i,1)
end do

stop
end
```

My data are numeric and I give an example of the input file:

```
    Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7 Var8 Var9 Var10 Var11 Var12 Var13 Var14 
7 40.548 23.166 772.55 13.7 0 23.59 13.7 20.99 115.31 9.8972 6.386902314 6.305332705 6.346117509 
7 40.611 23.101 771.01 7.25 0 13.2 7.25 23.17 185.01 14.948 7.138403639 6.926708182 7.032555911
 6 40.468 23.279 809.89 21.75 0 26.97 21.75 22.5 72.953 6.2802 5.659207146 5.619872819 5.639539983
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Please show the actual format of your data file. Some first rows of somethi.g. Then, also show the data structures of your code. Are  the x, y and z arrays or what are they? How are they declared? Do you know the number of rows? See [ask] and please be detailed and specific.

Comment: If you tried some code, show it.

Comment: @Vladimir F I posted above what I have tried so far

Comment: The code you show is really a mess and you should really study something first. Nevertheless, we really cannot show you anything more without you showing us the actual datafile. Just some example. We also do not know what you want to do with such data. The same data file can often be read into different data structures, there is no unique way how to read a data file. We do not even know if it is numeric data or character data or what kind of data it is.

Comment: My data is numeric and an example is in the attached above 

Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7 Var8 Var9 Var10 Var11 Var12 Var13 Var14
7 40.548 23.166 772.55 13.7 0 23.59 13.7 20.99 115.31 9.8972 6.386902314 6.305332705 6.346117509
7 40.611 23.101 771.01 7.25 0 13.2 7.25 23.17 185.01 14.948 7.138403639 6.926708182 7.032555911
6 40.468 23.279 809.89 21.75 0 26.97 21.75 22.5 72.953 6.2802 5.659207146 5.619872819 5.639539983


. I would like to make calculation between some comlumns of my input file (i.e. between 1st and third column etc)

Comment: Just cooy and paste the data, do not make photos.

Comment: Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7 Var8 Var9 Var10 Var11 Var12 Var13 Var14 7 40.548 23.166 772.55 13.7 0 23.59 13.7 20.99 115.31 9.8972 6.386902314 6.305332705 6.346117509 7 40.611 23.101 771.01 7.25 0 13.2 7.25 23.17 185.01 14.948 7.138403639 6.926708182 7.032555911 6 40.468 23.279 809.89 21.75 0 26.97 21.75 22.5 72.953 6.2802 5.659207146 5.619872819 5.639539983 .

Comment: Not here in the comments! [edit] your question. Put all important information there. And use the formatting buttons to format it as code.